# Shortest distance between a line segment and a point in WGS84 crs using geotools api

Tags: gis, geotools, wgs84

In geotools you can find distance between two geometries using the distance function in Geometry class. There is a Point subclass of Geometry but no line segment subclass of Geometry. There is however LineSegment class which derives from LineString which is not subclass of Geometry class. I tried using JTS but it appears as JTS is only for Cartesian coordinate system.

Question: How to find shortest distance (in meters) between a LineSegment and a Point in WGS84 crs.

Please note: I know there are answers available on SO for doing this without using geotools. Since we are using geotools in our project and code maintainability is very important I want to do it in geotools.

Comment: In my opinion, you have to convert your WGS84 coords to TM

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution (assuming that your point is *close* to the line is to use JTS to find the closest point (ignore curvature of the earth for now) and then use [GeodeticCalculator](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html) to find the distance between the two points. For short distances this should be fine.

If you need more accuracy you need to reproject you line(s) and point to a planar projection and do all the calculations in that projection using JTS directly.

PS LineString extends Geometry (check which sort of Geometry you have).