# What is the equivalent of GeoPy for Scala or Java?

Tags: scala, geolocation, geopy

Is GeoPy a wrapper of another implementation? Where can I find a Scala or Java equivalent solution to measure distances between two coordinates? Geotools does not work the way I want. For example, I have spotted a couple of cases in which the coordinates do not converge and return an error.

Comment: can you expand on why GeoTools doesn't do what you want? This is an easy and well known problem with an easy solution. e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132142/geotools-find-distance-in-meters-between-point-and-path-in-lat-lon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809534/shortest-distance-between-a-line-segment-and-a-point-in-wgs84-crs-using-geotools

Comment: Hi @iant. I made another post in regards to the non-converge issue I am currently facing. Can you please have a look and let me know what you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964589/geotools-distance-calculation-fails-with-no-convergence-exception-for-several-la

Answer (score 2):

The [GeographicLib-Java](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/java/) package (I wrote this) will do what you want.
It does all sorts of geodesic calculations on an ellipsoid.  The solution
for the distance between two points always converges.

Answer (score 1):

have also a look at [Geocalc](https://github.com/grumlimited/geocalc). I wrote it for one of my website

```
//Kew, London
Coordinate lat = new DegreeCoordinate(51.4843774);
Coordinate lng = new DegreeCoordinate(-0.2912044);
Point kew = new Point(lat, lng);

//Richmond, London
lat = new DegreeCoordinate(51.4613418);
lng = new DegreeCoordinate(-0.3035466);
Point richmond = new Point(lat, lng);

double distance = EarthCalc.getDistance(richmond, kew); //in meters
double distance = EarthCalc.getHarvesineDistance(richmond, kew); //in meters
double distance = EarthCalc.getVincentyDistance(richmond, kew); //in meters
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've worked with [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm), it's a very rich library for processing georeferenced data. If you want to use it in Scala it's not very idiomatic but I know [there's a binding library](https://github.com/lossyrob/jtscala) that may fit your needs.